# Multidimensional array value if exits

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I want to bring results that have a status 1 in the array.(Sorry i don't speak english)
My array is;

```
 [10100002] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ID] => 664
                    [barcode] => 10100002                   
                    [status] => 0
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ID] => 1339
                    [barcode] => 10100002                   
                    [status] => 0
                )

        )
 [10100004] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ID] => 1116
                    [barcode] => 10100004                   
                    [status] => 1
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ID] => 1826
                    [barcode] => 10100004                    
                    [status] => 0
                )

        )
```

in 10100002 two status is 0 but second array found status 1. if the status value is 1 in multiple arrays i like result this ;

```
[10100004] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ID] => 1116
                    [barcode] => 10100004                   
                    [status] => 1
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ID] => 1826
                    [barcode] => 10100004                    
                    [status] => 0
                )

        )
```

My code is here;

```
$result = array();
            foreach ($fetch_data as $value) {
              if($value->status== 1)
              $result[$value->barcode][] = $value;
            }
```

// this give me only one result. Output;

```
[10100004] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ID] => 1116
                    [barcode] => 10100004                   
                    [status] => 1
                )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_walk`

```
$arr = Array(
 '10100002' => Array
 (
    '0' => Array
        (
            'ID' => 664,
            'barcode' => 10100002,                
            'status' => 0
        ),

    '1' => Array
        (
            'ID' => 1339,
            'barcode' => 10100002,                  
            'status' => 0
        )

 ),
'10100004' => Array
(
    '0' => Array
        (
            'ID' => 1116,
            'barcode' => 10100004,                  
            'status' => 1
        ),

    '1' => Array
        (
            'ID' => 1826,
            'barcode' => 10100004,                 
            'status' => 0
        )

)
);
$res = [];
array_walk($arr, function($v, $k) use (&$res){
  foreach($v as $key => $value){
    if($value['status']){
       !empty($value['status']) ? ($res[$k][] = (object)$v[$key]) : '';
     }
 }
});
echo '<pre>';
print_r($res);
```

Output

```
Array
(
  [10100004] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [ID] => 1116
                [barcode] => 10100004
                [status] => 1
            )
     )
 )
```

[LIVE DEMO](https://3v4l.org/JgC7T)

Comment: thanks for help but result is this ` [10100004] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ID] => 1116
                    [barcode] => 10100004                   
                    [status] => 1
                )
)`

Comment: The result has not changed again output; [10100004] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 1116 [barcode] => 10100004 [status] => 1 ) )

Comment: @bxbx01 you have asked for this output, please check your comments

Comment: I'm sorry i speak little english. I like this output;[10100004] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ID] => 1116
                    [barcode] => 10100004                   
                    [status] => 1
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [ID] => 1826
                    [barcode] => 10100004                    
                    [status] => 0
                )

        )

Comment: @bxbx01 i have updated my asnwer copy , paste it and execute to see the putput

Comment: ok my friend tanks for answers your output not give me this `'1' => Array
        (
            'ID' => 1826,
            'barcode' => 10100004,                 
            'status' => 0
        )

)` i like all result if status 1 from barcode number 10100004